# Is it possible to read from a VBO?

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to make an OpenGL renderer that mashes various shapes into one large mesh and stores these in two VBOs, one GL_ARRAY_BUFFER and one GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER. I'm aiming for it to work on both OpenGL ES 2 and OpenGL 3.2 core.  I am currently trying to find the best way to handle deleting shapes from within this mesh and my current approach is to periodically rebuild the entire thing, possibly on a background thread.

The problem is that in order to rebuild the new and clean mesh, I need access to the vertices / indices that have been written to the buffers using glMapBuffer.  According to the documentation for [GL_OES_mapbuffer](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_mapbuffer.txt), WRITE_ONLY_OES is the only acceptable parameter for 'access'.

So, I don't think the data pointed at there is reliable to read from in order to create my new buffers.  I know there are other functions in GL Core that allow you to copy the buffer data, but these also seem to be missing.

Can anyone verify that this is not possible on ES 2.0 or give some approach for achieving buffer reading?  My current solution is to keep a shadow copy of all the data, which is obviously not ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that keeping a shadow copy of GPU data in main memory is much better than reading these data from GPU memory. It is recommended to discard previous data before using glMapBuffer anyway. Read [this](http://www.stevestreeting.com/2007/03/17/glmapbuffer-vs-glbuffersubdata-the-return/) for more information (It will not give you direct answer to your question, but it might be usefull).

Comment: Thanks for the advice - I feel the same about reading from the mapped buffer when you specifically request (albeit without an option)  write-only access.  I don't think the link is very relevant however, since I'm looking for a way to read or copy a VBO and that post has to do with the speed of writing in various ways.